# C# interface as parameter type conversion problem

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have this method...

```
public static IList<IOutgoingMessage> CompressMessages(IList<IOutgoingMessageWithUserAndPtMedInfo> msgs)
    {
        StoreOriginalMessages(msgs);
        ...
    }
```

which calls into this method...

```
 private static void StoreOriginalMessages(IList<IOutgoingMessage> msgs) {...}
```

and `IOutgoingMessageWithUserAndPtMedInfo` is defined like this...

```
public interface IOutgoingMessageWithUserAndPtMedInfo: IOutgoingMessage
{
    IPatientMedication PatientMedication { get; set; }
    IUserContainer User{ get; set; }
}
```

I getting this error when I try to call `StoreOriginalMessages` from my `CompressMessages` method:

*cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`<MyMediHealth.DataAccess.Containers.IOutgoingMessageWithUserAndPtMedInfo>`' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`<MyMediHealth.DataAccess.Containers.IOutgoingMessage>`'*

Don't understand why.  I would expect that it would accept it because `IOutgoingMessageWithUserAndPtMedInfo` inherits from `IOutgoingMessage`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From names of your methods I conclude that StoreOriginalMessages doesn't insert new elements in the list?

You could replace it by

```
private static void StoreOriginalMessages(IEnumerable<IOutgoingMessage> msgs)
```

And it should work smoothly (if you have C# 4.0 - before there was no covariance support unfortunately).

If you working with C# 3.5 you need to change call site as well:

```
StoreOriginalMessages(msgs.Cast<IOutgoingMessage>());
```

Answer (score 5):

Reference: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Assuming the following 2 interfaces and 2 classes:

```
interface IBase {}
interface IDerived : IBase {}

class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
```

If you do this, you'll get the same casting error:

```
IList<IDerived> lid = null;
IList<IBase> lib = lid; //cannot cast IList<IDerived> to IList<IBase>

IList<Derived> ld = null;
IList<Base> lb = ld; //cannot cast IList<Derived> to IList<Base>
```

However, the following will compile just fine, because `IEnumerable<T>` is declared for covariance, where `IList<T>` is not. `IEnumerable<T>` is actually `IEnumerable<out T>`, denoting that the type parameter is for return values only, and can allow covariance.

```
IEnumerable<IDerived> lid = null;
IEnumerable<IBase> lib = lid;

IEnumerable<Derived> ld = null;
IEnumerable<Base> lb = ld;
```

Comment: You most definitely can do this with interfaces, the issue is that IList<T> is not covariant in T. This was done because IList<T> exposes methods like Add that could break behavior under covariant scenarios (Adding a Tiger to a collection of Giraffes being used as a collection of Mammals). Use IEnumerable<T> instead and the code will work just fine.

Comment: @Chris: Your comment beat my edit. I iterate on my answers a lot.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation.  Have voted your answer up.